# router navigate not working while signing up with external url(referral url)?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I want my page to redirect to home page after user successfully signs up.

1) It works fine when i use below url.

```
http://localhost:4200/signup
```

2) But when i use a url with referral id like below

```
http://localhost:4200/referral/ONGMwyi1azt
```

it will redirect again to

```
http://localhost:4200/signup
```

Code:

```
signUp() {
  let params = {};
  params["action"] = "addUser";
  params["first_name"] = this.first_name;
  params["last_name"] = this.last_name;
  params["user_name"] = this.user_name;
  params["email_id"] = this.email_id;    
  params["password"] = sha256(this.password);


this._httpService.addUser(this.url, params).subscribe(resp => {
  if (
    resp["status"] === "User Registration Successful"      
  ) {     
    // this._zone.run(() => this._router.navigate(["/home"]));
    // setTimeout(() => this._router.navigate(["/home"]), 10);

     this._router.navigate(["/home"]);  
   }  

 });
}
```

And user successfully signs up **but not redirected to home page.**

What exactly the problem here while one case is working and the other is failing? Thank you.

Comment: Post some code where you are redirecting

Comment: Will you please share the actual logic (code) where you are redirecting to home page.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Please check routing module as i have mentioned, referral id should pass through routing time.

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [      
      { path: 'referral/:referralId', loadChildren: './Path/referral.module#ReferralModule' }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ReferralRoutingModule {}

2.You can use the below code in Referral Component. 

 constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute)
  ngOnInit() {
 this.referralId = this._route.snapshot.params['referralId'];
}
```

Comment: Thulasiram Virupakshi ---what is the 'loadChildren' value here ?

Comment: It is routing from parent to child component we have to mentioned like          
 
 1). If it is Load module mention like ,
 
 const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [      
      { path: 'referral/:referralId', loadChildren: './Path/referral.module#ReferralModule' }
    ]
  }
]; 2). If it is load child as component const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [      
      { path: 'referral/:referralId', component: ReffralComponent}
    ]
  }
];